# Can you lazy load any object? ie: a jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I'm building my portfolio website and I would like to have each portfolio piece be a small slideshow like http://www.christophermuccioli.com/. Which I have set up already.

I want this site to scroll horizontally, so as the user scrolls right more content (slideshows) is/are lazy loaded. Is it possible to lazy load the entire object? or is the script written specifically for images.

Anyone had experience doing something like this? I'd like some feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would that mean? Which loading to you want to be lazy?

Comment: Yikes, if you're a designer worth his salt you should be able to handle JS transition effects and AJAX calls like this I would think.

Comment: Yuck, thats a bit rude now isn't it, though I guess behind the veil of the web theres no need for manners.

Comment: SLaks, I have about 20 slide shows, each one features a different project. I've gotten each one inline so they display as one long horizontal row. So as the user scrolls I'd like to have more of the slideshows load in.

Answer (score 0):

If its fine then you could use some existing loazy loading ones, like:

http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel